# Display Name in GridControl

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, devexpress-windows-ui

I have got simple entities that are;

```
public class Customer
{
[Key]
public int ID { get; set; }

public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Provider
{
[Key]
public int ID { get; set; }

public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am using

```
 Devexpress LinqServerModeSource
 Devexpress Grid
```

I set datasource on run time.

Grid Column titles are **"ID"** and **"Name"**, 
but if i set datasource customer, i wanna see **"Customer Id"** and **"Customer Name"** or if i set datasource provider, i wanna see **"Provider Id"** and **"Provider Name"**

so Is there any way? annotation or vs..

Answer (score 0):

Set you Gridview's Auto "AutoGenerateColumns" property  true. And then assign data-source with columns names.

And as you are using Devexpress, you must set data-source in Page Init.
This is not perfect/complete code but you can get idea from this code block.

```
protected void Page_InIt(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGrid("Customers");
}

private void BindGrid(string strDataSourceType)
{
    var customers, providers = null;

    if (strDataSourceType == "Customers")
    {
        customers = (from x in Context.Customers
                     select new
                     {
                         CustomerId = x.ID,
                         CustomerName = x.Name
                     }).ToList();
    }
    else if (strDataSourceType == "Providers")
    {
        providers = (from x in Context.Providers
                     select new
                     {
                         ProviderId = x.ID,
                         ProviderName = x.Name
                     }).ToList();
    }

    grid.DataSource = customers / providers;
    grid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

Now, as you just want to change column name then you can do this way (Set Caption property),

```
foreach (DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GridViewDataColumn column in grid.Columns)
                {
                    if (column.FieldName == "Name")
                        column.Caption = "Customer Name";

                    if (column.FieldName == "ID")
                        column.Caption = "Customer ID";
                }
```

of if you know column order then you can set caption without using foreach loop.
you can do this,

grid.Columns[0].Caption = "Customer Name";
grid.Columns[1].Caption = "Customer ID";

Comment: my problem is only column title. i want to get column title from entity with annotation or else.

Comment: Then you can change column header from code behind.

Comment: thank you. I'm looking for solutions without writing code but i didn't find.